# is it possible to create a seperate log output file with Log4j for custom output

Tags: java, log4j

I want to output performance related data to a seperate log file. (Not Server.log).

For example in my class I want two loggers.

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyApp.class.getName());
static Logger logger_performance = Logger.getLogger(MyApp.class.getName());
```

The first spits out into the usual **server.log**. The second one should spit out data into **performance_data.log**. As I understand only one file can be configured with loggers?

Comment: Is it web-application?

Comment: Both loggers have the same name `MyApp.class.getName()` so `logger` and `logger_performance` are, in fact, the same object (well, 2 different pointers to the same object).

Comment: @zvzdhk its a rest service, and JEE application

Comment: Are you sure you are using `log4j` and not `java utils` for logging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just configure a second logger:

```
<logger name="your.class.logger" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="classlogger" />
</logger>

<logger name="performancelogger" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="performancelogger" />
</logger>


static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyApp.class.getName());
static Logger logger_performance = Logger.getLogger("performancelogger");
```

Comment: this should be in your log4j.xml config file. or maybe in the log4j.properties file, in case its not xml syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure multiple Appenders in log4j. For example, the `FileAppender` appends log output to a file.

See the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender) for details.